# Python decorators with function attributes

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-decorators

I have been experimenting with decorators and found an interesting inconsistency with them, hope you might help me to resolve it.

To begin with I had a decorator like this:

```
>>> def name(n):
...     def decorator(fun):
...             fun.name = n
...             return fun
...     return decorator
```

and I used it like so:

```
>>> @name("my name jeff")
... def f():
...     print f.name
```

since decorator returns fun I could do both:

```
>>> f()
my name jeff
>>> f.name
'my name jeff'
```

This was all fine and what I expected. Now comes the weird bit. My new decorator is as follows:

```
>>> def name(n):
...     def decorator(fun):
...             fun.name = n
...             def wrapper():
...                     return fun()
...             return wrapper
...     return decorator
```

To me it looks like this should do the same thing as the one before it, however I get this:

```
>>> @name("my name jeff")
... def f():
...     print f.__name__
...     print f.name
...
>>> f()
wrapper
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
 File "<stdin>", line 5, in wrapper
 File "<stdin>", line 4, in f
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Whats even more weird is the following:

```
>>> def f():
...     print f.__name__
...     print f.name
...
>>> x = name("jeff")(f)
>>> x.name
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'name'
>>> x()
f
jeff
```

Of course, x.name now fails since decorator returns wrapper and not fun. At the same time:

```
>>> f = name("jeff")(f)
>>> f()
wrapper
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "<stdin>", line 5, in wrapper
File "<stdin>", line 3, in f
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Furthermore:

```
>>> def name(n):
...     def decorator(fun):
...             fun.name = n
...             @wraps(fun)
...             def wrapper():
...                     return fun()
...             return wrapper
...     return decorator
...
>>> @name("my name jeff")
... def f():
...     print f.__name__
...     print f.name
...
>>> f()
f
my name jeff
```

Im not much of a python ninja so if Im missing something obvious please point it out.

Comment: Last script, line 4, `f` or `fun`?

Comment: Good catch, shoud be fun, will run this again, corrected

Comment: You seem to understand that your decorator returns `wrapper`, and not `fun`. So then what is your question exactly?

Comment: wrapper still calls fun in `return fun()`, I set attribute for `name` for `fun`, so why does it not work? And if it shouldn't work why does `x = name("jeff")(f)` work but not `f = name("jeff")(f)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your decorator is as follows:

```
>>> def name(n):
...     def decorator(fun):
...             fun.name = n
...             def wrapper():
...                     return fun()
...             return wrapper
...     return decorator
```

You're setting the `name` attribute for `fun`, but you're returning `wrapper`.
In other words, you replace `fun` by `wrapper`, that indeed has no `name` attribute.

You could try the following:

```
>>> def name(n):
...     def decorator(fun):
...             def wrapper():
...                     return fun()
...             wrapper.name = n
...             return wrapper
...     return decorator
```

Example:

```
>>> @name("hello")
... def f():
...     print(f.__name__)
...     print(f.name)
...     
>>> f()
wrapper
hello
```

Comment: but `wrapper` still calls `fun`, doesn't it? also, why would `x = name("jeff")(f)` work but not `f = name("jeff")(f)`, i replace `fun` in both cases

Comment: Oh, I see, its because f is globall.