# Can I use a global variable to parameter another function?

Tags: python, function, oop, global

I have a bbox_sort function to sort the coordinates in order from left to right. To take into account the Y height between the two bounding bbox, I start the thresh variable. In get_predict , the bbox_sort function is passed as an argument to cmp_to_key. I need to make optional parameter thresh

I know it's bad practice to use global variables, but I don't know how else to pass the thresh parameter to the bbox_sort function. Is it good practice to write the number thresh to a separate file and get it from there or how can I remake the sort function?

```py
from functools import cmp_to_key

def bbox_sort(a, b,):

    bbox_a = a
    bbox_b = b
    
    if abs(bbox_a[1] - bbox_b[1]) <= thresh: 
        return bbox_a[0] - bbox_b[0]
    
    return bbox_a[1] - bbox_b[1]

def get_prediction(result):
    coord_list = []
    res = result.to_coco_annotations()

    global thresh
    thresh = 10
    for ann in res:

        current_bbox = ann['bbox']
        x = current_bbox[0]
        y = current_bbox[1]
        w = current_bbox[2]
        h = current_bbox[3]
    
        coord_list.append((x, y, w, h))

    cnts = sorted(coord_list, key=cmp_to_key(bbox_sort))
    for pred in range(len(res)-1):
        res[pred]['image_id'] = cnts.index(tuple(res[pred]['bbox']))

    return res
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your threshold is a global variable only configurable by the developer it's common practice to define it on top of the file written in all caps `THRESHOLD = 10` right under your imports.

In python you only need to use `global ...` when you edit a global variable inside a function. (Which you don't plan on doing here, I assume.)

If the threshold isn't constant, and you want to be able to change it at runtime, you can wrap your function in a lambda like that:

`cnts = sorted(coord_list, key=cmp_to_key(lambda a,b: bbox_sort(a, b, thresh)))`

And then add a threshold to your arguments:

`def bbox_sort(a, b, threshold):`

Comment: actually just after the line `global thresh` there's the line `thresh = 10`

Comment: But if it's not changed anywhere else, id treat it as a constant and define it on top of the file.

Comment: Yes you are right. We don't see the rest of the code. So if the variable is really a constant you are right.

Comment: thresh must be a custom variable. Is it possible to prescribe THRESHOLD = 10 by default and add the thresh argument  (default 10
) to the get_prediction function, which will change THRESHOLD?

Comment: Then you can use a lambda and wrap your function that way `cnts = sorted(coord_list, key=cmp_to_key(lambda a,b: bbox_sort(a, b, thresh)))`. Then you don't need to use global variables at all.

Comment: Thank you very much !! It helped, I didn't know that you can supply a lambda as an argument

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `create_bbox_sort` function which creates a `bbox_sort` function on the fly using the `thresh` passed as a parameter to `create_bbox_sort`. This way, you don't need a global variable and the `create_bbox_sort` function can easily be used elsewhere and in other scripts. This is similar to the way [decorators with attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49174514/python-decorators-with-function-attributes) work.

The new code is :

```py
from functools import cmp_to_key

def create_bbox_sort(thresh):

    def bbox_sort(a, b,):

        bbox_a = a
        bbox_b = b
        
        if abs(bbox_a[1] - bbox_b[1]) <= thresh: 
            return bbox_a[0] - bbox_b[0]
        
        return bbox_a[1] - bbox_b[1]
    
    return bbox_sort

def get_prediction(result):
    coord_list = []
    res = result.to_coco_annotations()

    thresh = 10
    for ann in res:

        current_bbox = ann['bbox']
        x = current_bbox[0]
        y = current_bbox[1]
        w = current_bbox[2]
        h = current_bbox[3]
    
        coord_list.append((x, y, w, h))

    cnts = sorted(coord_list, key=cmp_to_key(create_bbox_sort(thresh)))
    for pred in range(len(res)-1):
        res[pred]['image_id'] = cnts.index(tuple(res[pred]['bbox']))

    return res
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice, I was already given a solution by passing a lambda function as an argument to cmp_to_key